# What are the best resources to learn JuMP?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I am new to JuMP / Julia. Do you have some suggestions or advice about how to learn it given that there are so few resources on the internet ?

Comment: Did you take a look at the [quick start guide](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/0.18/quickstart.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the fore mentioned [quick start guide](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/0.18/quickstart.html) and run the examples.

JuliaCon lectures are also a good source of information and can be found on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7tzFRIiseJI).

Once you get through there is a [collection of JuMP notebooks](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/juliaopt-notebooks/tree/master/notebooks) at JuliaOpt.

Using JuMP is simple. However, difficulty might arise due to frequent changes to APIs  and interoperability between versions (sometimes you will come across an example that  just does not work).

Comment: Thanks. I have mostly tried what you mentioned. That's true different versions is the main problem, especially when working with the .ipynb notebooks.